# Not able to capture Future events in Case of Event Viewer

Tags: c, windows, winapi, events

I was try to capture old and future windows events logs by subscribing "Security" channel. But i get only old Events and all future events are missing.

Currently working on Windows events Logs.
I want old events from specific event Record id and all future events.
for this I subscribe specific channel e.g. "Security" and try to capture events that i want.
But in case of Security channel for subscription i use "EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord" flag so that all old events and future events will be subscribed but I got only old events only and future events are missing.

```
EvtSubscribe (                                           
         NULL,                                           
         arrWaitHandle[1],                                           
         pwszChannel,                                        
         wsQuery,                                            
         NULL,                                           
         NULL,                                           
         NULL,                                           
         EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord                                             
         );
```

for subscribe the channel i Use above API and EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord flag because i want old events as well as future events but in case of "Security" channel I got only old events and future events are not captured.

I observe that in case of other channels e.g "Application" or "System" I got both old as well as future events.
But for "Security" channel I got only old Events.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in the code we cannot see. Show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I am able to capture both old events and future events with the domain admin account, with the following code, that's the sample on [Subscribing to Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wes/subscribing-to-events#push-subscriptions) and I've changed few of them:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winevt.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wevtapi.lib")

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

DWORD EnumerateResults(EVT_HANDLE hResults);
DWORD PrintEvent(EVT_HANDLE hEvent);
BOOL IsKeyEvent(HANDLE hStdIn);

void __cdecl wmain()
{
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    EVT_HANDLE hSubscription = NULL;
    HANDLE aWaitHandles[2];
    DWORD dwWait = 0;

    // Get a handle for console input, so you can break out of the loop.
    aWaitHandles[0] = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == aWaitHandles[0])
    {
        wprintf(L"GetStdHandle failed with %lu.\n", GetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Get a handle to a manual reset event object that the subscription will signal
    // when events become available that match your query criteria.
    aWaitHandles[1] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);
    if (NULL == aWaitHandles[1])
    {
        wprintf(L"CreateEvent failed with %lu.\n", GetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Subscribe to events.
    hSubscription = EvtSubscribe(NULL, aWaitHandles[1], L"Security", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord);
    if (NULL == hSubscription)
    {
        status = GetLastError();

        if (ERROR_EVT_CHANNEL_NOT_FOUND == status)
            wprintf(L"Channel was not found.\n");
        else if (ERROR_EVT_INVALID_QUERY == status)
            wprintf(L"The query was not found.\n");
        else
            wprintf(L"EvtSubscribe failed with %lu.\n", status);

        goto cleanup;
    }

    wprintf(L"Press any key to quit.\n");

    // Loop until the user presses a key or there is an error.
    while (true)
    {
        dwWait = WaitForMultipleObjects(sizeof(aWaitHandles) / sizeof(HANDLE), aWaitHandles, FALSE, INFINITE);

        if (0 == dwWait - WAIT_OBJECT_0)  // Console input
        {
            if (IsKeyEvent(aWaitHandles[0]))
                break;
        }
        else if (1 == dwWait - WAIT_OBJECT_0) // Query results
        {
            if (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != (status = EnumerateResults(hSubscription)))
            {
                break;
            }

            ResetEvent(aWaitHandles[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (WAIT_FAILED == dwWait)
            {
                wprintf(L"WaitForSingleObject failed with %lu\n", GetLastError());
            }
            break;
        }
    }

cleanup:

    if (hSubscription)
        EvtClose(hSubscription);

    if (aWaitHandles[0])
        CloseHandle(aWaitHandles[0]);

    if (aWaitHandles[1])
        CloseHandle(aWaitHandles[1]);
}

// Enumerate the events in the result set.
DWORD EnumerateResults(EVT_HANDLE hResults)
{
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    EVT_HANDLE hEvents[ARRAY_SIZE];
    DWORD dwReturned = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        // Get a block of events from the result set.
        if (!EvtNext(hResults, ARRAY_SIZE, hEvents, INFINITE, 0, &dwReturned))
        {
            if (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != (status = GetLastError()))
            {
                wprintf(L"EvtNext failed with %lu\n", status);
            }

            goto cleanup;
        }

        // For each event, call the PrintEvent function which renders the
        // event for display.
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwReturned; i++)
        {
            if (ERROR_SUCCESS == (status = PrintEvent(hEvents[i])))
            {
                EvtClose(hEvents[i]);
                hEvents[i] = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                goto cleanup;
            }
        }
    }

cleanup:

    // Closes any events in case an error occurred above.
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwReturned; i++)
    {
        if (NULL != hEvents[i])
            EvtClose(hEvents[i]);
    }

    return status;
}

// Render the event as an XML string and print it.
DWORD PrintEvent(EVT_HANDLE hEvent)
{
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;
    DWORD dwBufferUsed = 0;
    DWORD dwPropertyCount = 0;
    LPWSTR pRenderedContent = NULL;

    // The EvtRenderEventXml flag tells EvtRender to render the event as an XML string.
    if (!EvtRender(NULL, hEvent, EvtRenderEventXml, dwBufferSize, pRenderedContent, &dwBufferUsed, &dwPropertyCount))
    {
        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == (status = GetLastError()))
        {
            dwBufferSize = dwBufferUsed;
            pRenderedContent = (LPWSTR)malloc(dwBufferSize);
            if (pRenderedContent)
            {
                EvtRender(NULL, hEvent, EvtRenderEventXml, dwBufferSize, pRenderedContent, &dwBufferUsed, &dwPropertyCount);
            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"malloc failed\n");
                status = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
                goto cleanup;
            }
        }

        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != (status = GetLastError()))
        {
            wprintf(L"EvtRender failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
            goto cleanup;
        }
    }

    wprintf(L"\n\n%s", pRenderedContent);

cleanup:

    if (pRenderedContent)
        free(pRenderedContent);

    return status;
}

// Determines whether the console input was a key event.
BOOL IsKeyEvent(HANDLE hStdIn)
{
    INPUT_RECORD Record[128];
    DWORD dwRecordsRead = 0;
    BOOL fKeyPress = FALSE;

    if (ReadConsoleInput(hStdIn, Record, 128, &dwRecordsRead))
    {
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwRecordsRead; i++)
        {
            if (KEY_EVENT == Record[i].EventType)
            {
                fKeyPress = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return fKeyPress;
}
```

Common users do not have access to read Security logs. The Security log is designed for use by the system. However, users can read and clear the Security log if they have been granted the [`SE_SECURITY_NAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/privilege-constants) privilege (the "manage auditing and security log" user right).

UPDATE:

When I set the breakpoint into the event call back, the future events are also captured, but then nothing will be update to the console output. After pressing any key to quit, some inputs flashed across in the console. So I flush the console output buffer, Then solve the problem.

In function `DWORD PrintEvent(EVT_HANDLE hEvent)`:

```
{
   ...
   wprintf(L"\n\n%s", pRenderedContent);
   fflush(stdout);
   ...
}
```

Comment: but when i pass 2nd parameter to EvtSubscribe as   L" *[System[EventRecordID >RecordNo]]" then i only get old Events which satisfy the above query, and future events were not captured.

Comment: @ARJ It does seem like an error in Windows.(At least not be documented). I did the test, it occurs only when calling `EvtSubscribe` with `EventRecordID` + `EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord`. See this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a41a8cc-7ea9-4afc-8024-39e0b41ee3a7/evtsubscribe-on-application-channel-of-remote-with-pull-method-is-skipping-over-events?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) on msdn, Using the TimeCreated instead did work.

Comment: @ARJ, Suddenlly I find that after pressing any key to quit, some inputs flashed across in the console. SoI add a flush after `wprintf(L"\n\n%s", pRenderedContent);` , then slove the capture problem. See the update.